# how to split a string like char and number separately in swift

Tags: ios, swift, output

i am facing one issue about how to split a number and string in same String and display it. To be very clear lets take an example i have an string like,

```
myString = "MH04ED7897"
```

i want to my output like this

```
outPut = MH-04-ED-7897
```

Comment: Can you please share code which you have written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new in Swift. try this

```
let startIndex  = number.startIndex.advancedBy(4)
        let lastStr:String = number.substringFromIndex(startIndex)
        let InitialStr:String = number.substringToIndex(startIndex)

        NSLog("%@   %@", lastStr,InitialStr)


         let startInitialIndex  = InitialStr.startIndex.advancedBy(2)
         let InitialStart:String = InitialStr.substringToIndex(startInitialIndex)
         let Initialfinish:String = InitialStr.substringFromIndex(startInitialIndex)

        print("initalStart :\(InitialStart)")
        print("Initialfinish :\(Initialfinish)")

        let startlastIndex  = lastStr.endIndex.advancedBy(-4)

        let lastStart:String = lastStr.substringFromIndex(startlastIndex)

        let replaced = lastStr.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(lastStart, withString: "")

        print("replace:\(replaced)")

       // let lastFinish:String = lastStr.substringToIndex(startfirstIndex)

        print("lastStart :\(lastStart)")
```

you get output like
  [image]